# Does the Quran or any Hadith mentions the splitting of the Moon?

Tags: quran, hadith

Can someone please pinpoint me where exactly in the Quran/Hadith does it mention that the Moon was split into two and put back together again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes: https://quran.com/search?q=moon%20split :
quran 54:1, "Sahih International" traslation:

> The Hour has come near, and the moon has split [in two].

and there are 21 hadithes in a site of 13 hadith collections: https://sunnah.com/search/?q=moon%20split .

Comment: This verse is not unanimously interpreted as referring to something that has already happened; I think Hasan al-Basri for example is reported to have considered this verse as a description of Judgement Day. Other mufassirun gave similar interpretations.

Comment: @G.Bach However, [hadith specifically say](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2377/did-the-quran-mention-the-splitting-of-the-moon-as-a-miracle/2380#2380) that the moon splitting occurred during the lifetime of Muhammad (see previous answer).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Qur'an 54:1](https://quran.com/54/1), there are extensive reliable [ahadith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith):

> Narrated ['Abdullah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdullah_ibn_Masud): The moon was split (into two pieces) while we were with the Prophet (ﷺ) in Mina. He said, "Be witnesses." Then a Piece of the moon went towards the mountain. -- Sahih al-Bukhari 3869 ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3869)), and likewise Sahih al-Bukhari 3636 ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/61/140)) and Sahih al-Bukhari ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/urn/45420)) and Sahih Muslim 2800 a ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/muslim/52/27))
>
> [Ibn 'Umar](http://Ibn%20%27Umar) said: "The moon split during the time of the Messenger of Allah(s.a.w), so the Messenger of Allah(s.a.w) said: 'Bear witness."' -- Jami' at-Tirmidhi 2182 ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/33/25))
>
> Narrated [Ibn 'Abbas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdullah_ibn_Abbas):  The moon was split into two parts during the lifetime of the Prophet. -- Sahih al-Bukhari 3638 ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/61/142)), and likewise Sahih Muslim 2802 c ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/muslim/52/33))
>
> Narrated [Anas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anas_ibn_Malik):  That the Meccan people requested Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) to show them a miracle, and so he showed them the splitting of the moon. -- Sahih al-Bukhari 3637 ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/61/141); also [sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3868))
>
> Narrated Muhammad bin Jubair bin Mut'im:  from his father who said: "The moon was split during the time of the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) until it became as two sections, one above this mountain and one above that mountain. So they said: 'Muhammad has cast a spell upon us.' Some of them said: 'If he could cast a spell upon us, he can not cast a spell upon all of the people.'" -- Jami' at-Tirmidhi, Chapters on Tafsir [grade: sahih] ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/urn/643260))

So there's testimony from multiple companions of the Prophet that the moon indeed split in two.

Comment: Rebecca, if you'd like to add more to your answer, you might check this up: http://www.islamicity.com/quransearch/shownote.asp?chap=54&note=1 and http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=2&tSoraNo=54&tAyahNo=1&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=1